# Proof that Pearson correlation is/isn't a functional of the copula for a given pair of random variables

Tags: statistics, functional-equations, independence, correlation, copula

I have a growing interest and respect for the subject of [copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) initially thanks to comments made on stats.SE by [kjetil-b-halvorsen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen). The most interesting to me right now is the following:

> "[[T]he Pearson correlation is not a functional of the copula[.]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535145/how-can-a-copula-be-seen-as-a-characterization-of-association)"

My understanding is that if two random variables are stochastically independent, then their Pearson correlation will be zero. The converse does not hold, which I have believed to be the case in the sense that correlation only quantifies dependence in a narrow sense. The (possibly unique depending on continuity) copula between a joint cumulative distribution and its marginals seems to specify the type of dependence. It surprises me that there wouldn't be a mapping from the copula to the Pearson correlation function (of a given collection of random variables) that "loses information" about the exact dependence, leaving only a measure of dependence in the more narrow linear sense.

Is there a (dis)proof of this assertion?

Comment: Footnote: Contrary to some introductory materials on Pearson correlation, I am not assuming that the variables are Gaussian. Distribution choice affects some properties of the correlation, but not the fact that if $X,Y$ are independent then $\mathbb{E}[(X- \mathbb{E}[X])(Y- \mathbb{E}[Y])] = 0$.

Comment: I do not fully understand: "[So the maximal correlation possible is actually only 0.944, compared with the actual value of 0.934. And since the log transformation preserves the copula, but not the Pearson correlation, we see that it is not marginal free.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association)"

Comment: Marginal Free: "[A stronger requirement would be that A is marginal free, that is, it only depends on the bivariate distribution through its copula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the remark simply means that you can have different joint distributions with the same copula but different Pearson correlation. So the copula alone does not determine the correlation; the correlation also depends on the marginals.

Take, for example, the bivariate copula that has density $c(u,v) = 2$ when $u,v$ are both $\le 1/2$ or both $>1/2$, and zero otherwise. If you take $U$ and $V$ both uniform over $(0,1)$ with this joint distribution, you have $\rho_{U,V} = 0.75$. Then let $X=U^3$ and $Y=V^3$; now $(X,Y)$ has still the same copula but $\rho_{X,Y} \approx 0.595$.

[image: Simulation]

Here's a more drastic example where $\rho_{U,V}$ and $\rho_{X,Y}$ have different *signs*. Here the copula density is $3$ in the three small squares, and the nonlinear transformation is again $(X,Y)=(U^3,V^3)$.

[image: Another simulation]

On the other hand, if you know the copula *and* the marginals, then you know the joint distribution so surely the correlation is then determined.

Comment: I like where this answer is going. I don't think a copula can be $C(u,v) = 2$, but I suspect this is a typo. Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant that the copula has that *density*. (Not cdf!) I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the additional example. Showing that the sign can change gives an even stronger example that the correlation is not completely dependent on the copula.